# Google Sheets: Replace cell contents with another cell contents when "Clicked"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

### Google Sheets: Replace cell contents with another cell contents when "Clicked" ?

I'm trying to create an easy way to reveal more data from a row when any cell is clicked from the row it lives in. Currently, I have a nice `=VLOOKUP("*") ...` function that allows me to type in a `COMPANY` name into a "search bar" cell, and then VLOOKUP will display cell contents depending on which `COMPANY` it is.

**You can see it in action here:**
[Google Sheets Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a1sk86VVTpQMHgqSK4iiGeIZIXPyfpnI3GMqzHQSxR4/edit?usp=sharing)

> #### How To Use:
>
> **Green Cells:** Type in the "Search Bar" cell for a company name... 
> **Orange Cells:** If "COMPANY" is found, it displays the companies cell contents to the left.

## What I want to do:

1. Click on a cell in any row
2. Have that cell realize what row it's in and navigate to the `COMPANY` column.
3. Copy the cells contents from the `COMPANY` column and replace the current contents of the "search bar" cell
4. VLOOKUP will then handle the rest.

---

### Possible?

Is this possible with Google Sheet functions alone? Or is this something that should be handled with a script? How would I got about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to create an onClick function. The closest thing we have is an onEdit() function. I can think of two ways to make this sort of work.

**1)** This onEdit version works only if you don't mind locking your script down. You could write an IF statement to create a way to stop this from running temporarily while you edit it.
**2)** You could setup a second sheet and have the values imported from there or backed up there, and then just run this on the first one at all times.

```
function onEdit(e) {
//This sets up the worksheet variables
 var worksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = worksheet.getActiveSheet();
//This saves the original value e
 var origValue = e.oldValue
//This figures out where you clicked, and gets the K+rowyouclicked value.
 var selection = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
 var splitselection = selection.match(/([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)/);
 var CompName = sheet.getRange("K" + splitselection[2]).getValue();
//set the value on the search bar and return the original value to where you changed.
 sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(CompName);
 sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(origValue)
}
```

Comment: Great! I'll give it a go

Comment: If it works, mark the questions answered to help future searchers @Oneezy

Comment: I'm trying to make option 2) work that you've given. I've setup another sheet called "_data" that I'm importing into the main sheet w/  the functions and script, "CLIENTS".  I'm getting this error message in the script: 

TypeError: Cannot read property "oldValue" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a1sk86VVTpQMHgqSK4iiGeIZIXPyfpnI3GMqzHQSxR4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the script and the error message:
http://oneezy.com/stackoverflow/script-replace-contents.png

Comment: @Oneezy Are you clicking the RUN button? Or are you just saving it and changing a value? You're supposed to do the latter. Let it run once you change an active cell. If that's what you're doing and its giving you that error message its because my script didn't have any error checking for if the original value was blank. So either write that in, or just only change a cell that already had a value in it.

Comment: i was.. yes. I just tried the latter and it's almost* working. when clicking on a cell it doesn't do anything, then i tried double clicking a cell and it didn't do anything, then i tried typing into a cell and it updated the value in the search bar with the correct contents but then it breaks. Have a look a look at this quick video I just recorded to see what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWs1ZytGnPo